# How to set up ALLOWED_HOSTS in digital ocean

Tags: django, digital-ocean

I successfully hosted my Django code in digital ocean with DNS.After hosted I'm getting weird output in my browser.

when I enter `example.com`.i'm getting the login page after logged in I'm reached my home page.all works fine.But when I enter `www.example.com` I'm redirected to my login page.then again I test `example.com` it shows homepage, not the login page. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

**my ALLOWED_HOSTS look like this initially**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com','example.com']
```

**Then I changed it to:**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com']
```

**last try**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]
```

I changed multiple things but the result is same.Any help really appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in settings below settings then Django will redirect user to automatic on www.example.com

```
PREPEND_WWW = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.example.com']
```

If user enter http://example.com then Django will redirect http://www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.py`,

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com']
```

But i recommend to do like non-www -> www or www->non-www permanent redirect.It can be done webserver itself before touching django.

Comment: In ALLOWED_HOSTS=['.example.com']?